# Arduino string comparison not working when using String str_out = String((char*)buf);

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am successfully receiving data over RF on a second Arduino. However I am trying to compare the incoming string so that I can call a method when there is a match. The "if" block is never executed. I am just trying to compare the strings that are incoming. It's printing the correct values to the serial monitor but the block is never executed. Maybe because this is using a pointer to a string (don't shoot me)? I am not that familiar with C or C++. I have tried several of the string comparison methods in the Arduino docs but no joy? Any reccomendations?

```
void loop()
{
// Set buffer to size of expected message
uint8_t buf[7];
uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
// Check if received packet is correct size
if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen))
{
  
  // Message received with valid checksum
  Serial.print("Message Received: ");
  String str_out = String((char*)buf);
  Serial.println(str_out); / 

  if (str_out == "plasma1") { // this is never executed wtf!!!
     plasmaSequenceOne();
  } else if (str_out == "plasma2") {
     plasmaSequenceTwo();
  } else if (str_out == "plasma3") {
     plasmaSequenceThree();
  } else if (str_out == "plasma4") {
     plasmaSequenceFour();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: `"plasma1"` cannot fit inside a `uint8_t [7]`, you need one extra byte for the NUL terminator.

Comment: I increased to `uint8_t [8]` and it is printing "plasma18"??

Comment: Is the data that `rf_driver.recv()` receives null-terminated? Imagine what happens if `buf` is not null-terminated when `String((char*)buf)` is called, since there is no `String()` constructor that accepts a length (AFAICS).  So, I would use `uint8_t buf[8]`, but set `buflen=7`, and then set `buf[buflen]=0` before calling `String((char*)buf)`.  Otherwise, does Arduino have `memcmp()`?

Comment: @AlexMcPherson then I suspect data stored in `buf` is not NUL-terminated as Remy also points out. You can manually add a `\0'` at the end of `buf`.

Comment: `==` in `str_out == "plasma1"`  looks suspicious because you compare *pointer*, not the content of the strings. Consider `strcmp`. Is it C or C++? Please select only one of those tags

Comment: @tstanisl `str_out` is of type `String` though. According to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/StringComparisonOperators), I think `String` has a `operator==` overload (But I can't be sure, I know little to nothing about Arduino).

Comment: @AlexMcPherson `if (str_out == "plasma1") { // this is never executed wtf!!` -- If you were to inspect what `str_out` contained, you will probably see `plasma1` followed by "junk".  Or even better yet, print out the `size()` (or whatever the member function is for `String`) to get the actual size of `str_out`.  Don't be surprised if it isn't 7.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're the man using `uint8_t buf[8]`, but set `buflen=7`, and then set `buf[buflen]=0` before calling `String((char*)buf)` did the trick. The library in question is C++

Comment: @AlexMcPherson -- Doesn't `String` have a constructor that takes a pointer and the number of elements?  If it does, you don't have to go all through all of these hoops setting elements to 0.  Bottom line -- you are using the wrong functions for the data you are getting -- don't use functions that require null-termination (like the `String` constructor you were using).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "*Doesn't `String` have a constructor that takes a pointer and the number of elements?*" - [no, it doesn't](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/), it seems.  That was the first thing I looked for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- Then my opinion -- the `String` class is lacking.  Probably many other programmers have said the same thing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie correct if I loop over the chars it’s 8 not 7 characters so it’s clearly not nul terminated so I have junk on the end. Not experienced enough with C or C++ so was stumped. Thank god for higher level langs is all I’ll say

Answer (score 1):

Making Alex' self-response easier readable, and avoiding unnecessary String objects:

```
uint8_t buf[8];
uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf)-1;  // leave space for terminating 0
if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {
    buf[buflen] = 0;
    char* str_out = (char*)buf; 
    Serial.println (str_out);
    if (strcmp(str_out, "plasma1")==0) plasmaSequenceOne();
    ...
}
```

This worked, thanks to @Remy Lebeau.